# What is the diference between using base images and using apt?

Tags: python, docker, apache, dockerfile

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20274162/10666216) and I understand that you need some kind of foundation to build your docker image. However, I still don't see the purpose of docker images like [python](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/).

Why do I need this:

```
FROM python:latest
```

when I can just do that:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt install python3
```

Say I want to run a container where a python server is hosted using apache. What would be the difference between

1. Using the apache base image and installing python manually
2. Using the python base image and installing apache manually
3. Using the ubuntu base image and installing both manually

Comment: In principle there is no difference but the details of each image may vary.

Comment: You can actually check out what's in the python image [here](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/afc4106edc395bed8dfe7a497444033b12452406/3.9/buster/Dockerfile)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is slim in the given example because in the end you will get the same thing but using slightly different commands.

Things change when you need to use either latest or specific version of the software. The required version may not be available in standard Ubuntu repositories or may come with a delay.

What you get from using `python` or `apache2` as a base is the ability to choose the version you need with just one line of code as soon as it's published.

More significantly, there may be no need to combine python and apache. Docker containers are usually made to host a single process and it is more common to have a python backend in one container and a web-server as a proxy in another.

In this case you don't care about installing apache at all, you just mount its config into the container at runtime. Eliminating the web server you only need to focus on the application and its dependencies, so in the end you will have less code and easier time maintaining it.